# Pasar texto a json en python

Tags: python, json

He hecho un script que te coge datos de monitorización de ldap y te los devuelve en este texto:

> [[('cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 0,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 1,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 2,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 3,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 4,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Backend
> 5,cn=Backends,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Connections,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Connection 1003,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorConnectionRead': ['2'], 'monitorConnectionGet': ['2'],
> 'monitorConnectionOpsReceived': ['2'],
> 'monitorConnectionOpsCompleted': ['1'], 'monitorConnectionNumber':
> ['1003'], 'monitorConnectionWrite': ['0'],
> 'monitorConnectionOpsExecuting': ['1'], 'monitorConnectionOpsPending':
> ['0']})], [('cn=Max File Descriptors,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['1024']})],
> [('cn=Total,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor', {'monitorCounter':
> ['1004']})], [('cn=Current,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['1']})], [('cn=Databases,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Frontend,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Database
> 0,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Database
> 1,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Database
> 2,cn=Databases,cn=Monitor', {'olmBDBEntryCache': ['0'],
> 'olmBDBIDLCache': ['0'], 'olmBDBDNCache': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Listener
> 0,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Listener
> 1,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Listener
> 2,cn=Listeners,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Log,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['11'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['10']})], [('cn=Bind,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorOpInitiated': ['4'], 'monitorOpCompleted': ['4']})],
> [('cn=Unbind,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['3'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['3']})],
> [('cn=Search,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['4'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['3']})],
> [('cn=Compare,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Modify,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Modrdn,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})], [('cn=Add,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'], 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Delete,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Abandon,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated': ['0'],
> 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})],
> [('cn=Extended,cn=Operations,cn=Monitor', {'monitorOpInitiated':
> ['0'], 'monitorOpCompleted': ['0']})], [('cn=Overlays,cn=Monitor',
> {})], [('cn=Overlay 0,cn=Overlays,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=SASL,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Bytes,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor', {'monitorCounter':
> ['17115']})], [('cn=PDU,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor', {'monitorCounter':
> ['229']})], [('cn=Entries,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['223']})],
> [('cn=Referrals,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor', {'monitorCounter':
> ['0']})], [('cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Max,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Max
> Pending,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Open,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Starting,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Active,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Pending,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Backload,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=State,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Runqueue,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Tasklist,cn=Threads,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Time,cn=Monitor',
> {})], [('cn=Start,cn=Time,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Current,cn=Time,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Uptime,cn=Time,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=TLS,cn=Monitor', {})],
> [('cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor', {})], [('cn=Read,cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['1']})], [('cn=Write,cn=Waiters,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['0']})]]

Como se puede ver en la docu de openldap cogo los datos de monitorizacion de casi todo : https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin25/monitoringslapd.html

Si haces una busqueda personalizada de algun apartado como el de las conexiones por ejemplo (esto me refiero desde el terminal, no en el script) te devuelve esta información de monitoreo :

Total Connections:

dn: cn=Total,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor
structuralObjectClass: monitorCounterObject
monitorCounter: 4
entryDN: cn=Total,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

Ami solo me interesa "dn" como identificativo y "monitorCounter" como valor, por eso hago una busqueda de todo "Monitor" usando esos dos atributos y me devuelve el texto antes mencionado.

Esto lo hago con la biblioteca python-ldap que da bastantes facilidades para esto, despues de autenticarme en el codigo uso este try para recoger los datos y mostrarlos :

```
try:    
    ldap_result_id = l.search(basedn, searchScope, searchFilter, searchAttribute)
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if (result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            ## if you are expecting multiple results you can append them
            ## otherwise you can just wait until the initial result and break out
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                result_set.append(result_data)
    print result_set
```

Donde :

```
basedn = "cn=Monitor"
searchFilter = '(objectClass=*)' 
searchAttribute = ['dn','monitorCounter']
#this will scope the entire subtree under UserUnits
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
```

Es decir ese texto es el resultado de haber cogido los datos que me interesan y meterlos en result_set[].

Pero ese formato es complejo, y necesito los datos en otro como json o xml para poder cargarlos en un software en el que instalaras este script que estoy haciendo.

Lo ideal seria en el json tenerlos como identificativo : valor, como por ejemplo esto :

> [('cn=PDU,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor', {'monitorCounter':
> ['229']})], [('cn=Entries,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor',
> {'monitorCounter': ['223']})],

donde 'cn=PDU,cn=Statistics,cn=Monitor' sería el identificativo y {'monitorCounter': ['229']} el valor.

es decir lo ideal sería algo asi como : PDUStatics:229

No se si se podría hacer esto o es muy complejo.

Comment: 1) Los datos tienen una jerarquía compleja; ¿cómo esperas representar esa información en el JSON? 2) Has hecho varias preguntas similares cuyas respuestas deberían ser suficientes para esta pregunta. 3) No aportas ningún código para empezar, ni ejemplo suficientemente ilustrativo de la salida que deseas.

Comment: Hola, con el ejemplo que me pusiste en otro post creo que me valdría pero tengo algunas dudas, no podríamos comunicarnos por otro lado y te lo explico mejor?

Comment: En tal caso nadie más se enteraría, y la solución se perdería. Mejor arregla la pregunta, para que la(s) respuesta(s) queden  visibles para la comunidad y futuros usuarios.

Comment: Por otra parte, soy enemigo de usar el chat para responder preguntas. Lo encuentro desorganizado y extenuante, además que todo es un esfuerzo perdido, pues del chat nada queda.

Comment: Vale, he actualizado la pregunta, creo que ahora se entiende más.

Comment: Veo que la cadena de texto ya trae un estructura json. lo que puedes hacer es. `result_set` convertirlo a `json`. de esta manera.  `y = json.loads(result_set)`   (tienes que importar el modulo json. con eso ya puedes acceder al indice que quieras obtener

Comment: he probado y me da este error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandora_ldapjson.py", line 47, in <module>
    y = json.loads(result_set)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: vale con json.dumps ya no me da el error

Answer (score 1):

**Convierte el texto con estructura json.**

```
import json
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(y["age"])
```

**Para buscar un texto en la cadena**

```
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
     existe=false
     error = re.search("John", x)
              if error is not None:
                 if error.group()=="John":
                  existe = True
                 else:
                  existe =False
                  
             else:
                 existe = False
```